# Android reflection to get HTML file in package

Tags: android

I am trying to get a HTML file that I packaged together with the rest of the Java source codes. It worked for Desktop Java, but does not work for Android.

So now, the code:

```
public static String getContentString(final String uri){
    if(Misc.stringHasContent(uri)){
//uri = "/app/myapp/html/myHTMLFile.html"
        URL url = MyClass.class.getResource(uri);
        if(url != null){
            try{
                Object object = url.getContent();
                InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) url.getContent();
                final int available = inputStream.available();

                byte[] contentBytes = new byte[available];
                inputStream.read(contentBytes);
                return new String(contentBytes);
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`url` is null after the getResource() method call, no Exception was thrown and the method just quits and return a null String.

How do I get it to work in Android?

Comment: What is getResource returning specifically? Without knowing that we can't say.

Comment: getResource() is a method that comes with the Class Object, and it returns the URL Object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is compiled into a dex file inside your APK (classes.dex) and all resources are saved as a tree at the base of your APK. Because of this, `ResourceBundle.getBundle(String)` or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(String)` will return `null`.

On Android, you should be putting resources in assets or res/raw.